# jquery click button action to hide or show text

Tags: jquery

When I click post 1 or 2 or 3 button, gold text will be hidden, next time I will click I want silver text to be hidden. And finally I will click post 3 I want browse text to be hidden. It works first time and next time will not work.

```
<div>

<p id="gg">Gold</p>

<p id="ss">Silver</p>

<p id="bb">Browse</p>

<button id="cancel">Cancel</button><br/><br/>

<button id="post1" value="">Post 1</button><br/><br/>
<button id="post2" value="">Post 2</button><br/><br/>
<button id="post3" value="">Post 3</button>

</div>

<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){


        $("#post1").click(function(){
        //$("#g").hide();

        if ($('#gg:visible') && $('#ss:visible') && $('#bb:visible')) {  
            $("#gg").hide();
        }

        else if ($('#gg').is(':hidden') && $('#ss:visible') && $('#bb:visible')) {  
            $("#ss").hide();
            //alert('s')
        }
        else{
            $("#bb").hide();
        }
        });

        $("#post2").click(function(){
        //$("#g").hide();

        if ($('#gg:visible') && $('#ss:visible') && $('#bb:visible')) {  
            $("#gg").hide();
        }

        else if ($('#gg').is(':hidden') && $('#ss:visible') && $('#bb:visible')) {  
            $("#ss").hide();
            //alert('s')
        }
        else{
            $("#bb").hide();
        }

        });

        $("#post3").click(function(){
        //$("#g").hide();

        if ($('#gg:visible') && $('#ss:visible') && $('#bb:visible')) {  
            $("#gg").hide();
        }

        else if ($('#gg').is(':hidden') && $('#ss:visible') && $('#bb:visible')) {  
            $("#ss").hide();
            //alert('s')
        }
        else{
            $("#bb").hide();
        }

        });

    $("#cancel").click(function(){
        $("p").show();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Of course it will not work: You are leaving the exact same three conditions after you have changed one of the elements(visibility) state. So that IF statements will never evaluate to true.

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: Well if just want to remove it onece and forever then just don't put any condition at all. If you want to toggle its visibility (hide/visible) you might want to use jquery.toggle function for easier/faster approach. http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 1):

change your javascript to be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


        $("#post1, #post2, #post3").click(function(){


        if ($('#gg').is(':visible') && $('#ss').is(':visible') && $('#bb').is(':visible')) {  
            $("#gg").hide();
        }

        else if ($("#gg").is(":hidden") && $('#ss').is(':visible') && $('#bb').is(':visible')) {  
            $("#ss").hide();

        }
        else{
            $("#bb").hide();
        }
        });



    $("#cancel").click(function(){
        $("p").show();
    });
});
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wpcwbhrj/) of it working

Comment: thanks now it ok, Please guide me i want to add change color of click button color after clicking

Comment: Can I get value of click id when I click this function. Bcoz I want to know what div id user click .